# how can i get filename from user input in dos asm

Tags: assembly, dosbox

i'm making a console program,and my file procedures need filename,though,i wanna get the filename from user input,so when you write in the console /r, you can write until max 15 letters,containing the .txt in the filename,but it seems like my code isnt working,how can i get the filename from user input into a string or to this variable     `filename db "filename.txt",0`?

my Openfile proc (for example):

```
proc OpenFile
;Open file
    mov ah,3Dh
    xor al,al
    lea dx,[filename]
    int 21h
    jc openerror
    mov [filehandle],ax
    ret
openerror:  
    mov dx,offset ErrorOpenMsg
    mov ah,9h
    int 21h
    ret
endp OpenFile
```

ORIGINAL-full code:

```
IDEAL
MODEL small
STACK 100h
DATASEG

szMsg1 db "Hi! What do you want to do?",10,13,10,13,"/h-help(see all the commands)",10,13,"/e-Exit",10,13,10,13,"$"
szHelloWorld db 10,13,"Hello World!",10,13,"$"
ErrorMsg db 10,13,"Illegal Command,Try again!",10,13,"$"
filenameStr db 15 dup(?),0
help db 10,13,"HELP LIST:",10,13,"-----------",10,13,"Commands are:",10,13," /e-Exit",10,13," /h-help",10,13," /1-Says: 'Hello World!'",10,13,"$"
filename db ?,0
filehandle dw 0
ErrorOpenMsg db 'Error',10,13,'$'
FileNameLength db "file name consists of 8 letters max! (dont forget to add '.txt' at the end of the name: 'example.txt')",10,13,"/r/ ","$"
fileString db 255 dup (0)
space db " ","$"
CommandMsg db 10,13,"Enter your command:",10,13,"Command: ","$",10,13
string db ?

CODESEG                                    
proc OpenFile
;Open file
    mov ah,3Dh
    xor al,al
    lea dx,[filenameStr]
    int 21h
    jc openerror
    mov [filehandle],ax
    ret
openerror:  
    mov dx,offset ErrorOpenMsg
    mov ah,9h
    int 21h
    ret
endp OpenFile   

proc ReadFile
    mov ah,3fh
    mov bx,[filehandle]
    mov cx,255
    lea dx,[string]
    int 21h
    ret
endp ReadFile   

proc DeleteFile
    mov ah,41h
    lea dx,[filename]
    int 21h
endp DeleteFile

proc DisplayFileString
    mov ah,09h
    lea dx,[fileString]
    int 21h 
endp DisplayFileString  

proc KeyStroke
    xor ax,ax
    int 16h
endp KeyStroke

proc WriteToFile
    mov ah,40h
    mov bx,[filehandle]
    mov cx,255
    lea dx,[fileString]
    int 21h
    ret
endp WriteToFile

proc CloseFile
    mov ah,3Eh
    mov bx,[filehandle]
    int 21h
    ret
endp CloseFile  

start:
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

    mov dx,offset szMsg1
    mov ah,9h
    int 21h
    jmp GetCommandLetter

_Error:

    mov dx,offset ErrorMsg
    mov ah,9h
    int 21h 

GetCommandLetter:
    mov dx,offset CommandMsg
    mov ah,9h
    int 21h

    mov ah, 1h
    int 21h
    mov bl,al   

    mov ah, 1h
    int 21h
    mov bh,al   
compare:    
    cmp bl,'/'
    jne _Error
    cmp bh,'e'
    je _exit

    cmp bl,'/'
    jne _Error
    cmp bh,'E'
    je exit

    cmp bl,'/'
    jne _Error
    cmp bh,'h'
    je _help

    cmp bl,'/'
    jne _Error
    cmp bh,'H'
    je _help

    cmp bl,'/'
    jne _Error
    cmp  bh,'1'
    je PrintLine

    mov dx,offset space
    mov ah,9h
    int 21h
    mov dx,offset FileNameLength
    mov ah,9h
    int 21h

    cmp bl,'/'
    jne _Error
    cmp  bh,'r'
    je GetFileName

    cmp bl,'/'
    jne _Error
    cmp  bh,'R'
    je GetFileName

    jmp _Error
_exit:
    jmp exit    

GetFileName:
    mov dx,offset space
    mov ah,9h
    int 21h

    mov dx,offset filenameStr
    mov bx,dx
    mov [byte ptr bx],15
    mov ah,0Ah
    int 21h
    mov dx,offset filenameStr
    mov ah,9h
    int 21h
    call OpenFile
    call ReadFile
    call CloseFile
    jmp GetCommandLetter



_help:  
    mov dx,offset help
    mov ah,9h
    int 21h
    jmp GetCommandLetter

PrintLine:
    mov dx, offset szHelloWorld
    mov ah, 9h
    int 21h
    jmp GetCommandLetter

exit:
    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h
END start



    mov [filehandle],ax
    ret
openerror:  
    mov dx,offset ErrorOpenMsg
    mov ah,9h
    int 21h
    ret
endp OpenFile   

proc ReadFile
    mov ah,3fh
    mov bx,[filehandle]
    mov cx,255
    lea dx,[string]
    int 21h
    ret
endp ReadFile   

proc DeleteFile
    mov ah,41h
    lea dx,[filename]
    int 21h
endp DeleteFile

proc DisplayFileString
    mov ah,09h
    lea dx,[fileString]
    int 21h 
endp DisplayFileString  

proc KeyStroke
    xor ax,ax
    int 16h
endp KeyStroke

proc WriteToFile
    mov ah,40h
    mov bx,[filehandle]
    mov cx,255
    lea dx,[fileString]
    int 21h
    ret
endp WriteToFile

proc CloseFile
    mov ah,3Eh
    mov bx,[filehandle]
    int 21h
    ret
endp CloseFile  

start:
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

    mov dx,offset szMsg1
    mov ah,9h
    int 21h
    jmp GetCommandLetter

_Error:

    mov dx,offset ErrorMsg
    mov ah,9h
    int 21h 

GetCommandLetter:
    mov dx,offset CommandMsg
    mov ah,9h
    int 21h

    mov ah, 1h
    int 21h
    mov bl,al   

    mov ah, 1h
    int 21h
    mov bh,al   
compare:    
    cmp bl,'/'
    jne _Error
    cmp bh,'e'
    je _exit

    cmp bl,'/'
    jne _Error
    cmp bh,'E'
    je exit

    cmp bl,'/'
    jne _Error
    cmp bh,'h'
    je _help

    cmp bl,'/'
    jne _Error
    cmp bh,'H'
    je _help

    cmp bl,'/'
    jne _Error
    cmp  bh,'1'
    je PrintLine

    mov dx,offset space
    mov ah,9h
    int 21h
    mov dx,offset FileNameLength
    mov ah,9h
    int 21h

    cmp bl,'/'
    jne _Error
    cmp  bh,'r'
    je GetFileName

    cmp bl,'/'
    jne _Error
    cmp  bh,'R'
    je GetFileName

    jmp _Error
_exit:
    jmp exit    

GetFileName:
    mov dx,offset space
    mov ah,9h
    int 21h

    mov dx,offset filenameStr ;setting letters into string from input
    mov bx,dx
    mov [byte ptr bx],15
    mov ah,0Ah
    int 21h
    mov dx,offset filenameStr ;output of the string,string input supposidly bad
    mov ah,9h
    int 21h
    call OpenFile
    call ReadFile
    call CloseFile
    jmp GetCommandLetter



_help:  
    mov dx,offset help
    mov ah,9h
    int 21h
    jmp GetCommandLetter

PrintLine:
    mov dx, offset szHelloWorld
    mov ah, 9h
    int 21h
    jmp GetCommandLetter

exit:
    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h
END start
```

NEW-full code:

```
IDEAL
MODEL small
STACK 100h
DATASEG

szMsg1 db "Hi! What do you want to do?",10,13,10,13,"/h-help(see all the commands)",10,13,"/e-Exit",10,13,10,13,"$"
szHelloWorld db 10,13,"Hello World!",10,13,"$"
ErrorMsg db 10,13,"Illegal Command,Try again!",10,13,"$"
filenameStr db 13,0,13 dup("$")
help db 10,13,"HELP LIST:",10,13,"-----------",10,13,"Commands are:",10,13," /e-Exit",10,13," /h-help",10,13," /1-Says: 'Hello World!'",10,13,"$"
filename db ?,0
filehandle dw 0
ErrorOpenMsg db 'Error',10,13,'$'
FileNameLength db "file name consists of 8 letters max! (dont forget to add '.txt' at the end of the name: 'example.txt')",10,13,"/r/ ","$"
fileString db 255 dup (0)
space db " ","$"
CommandMsg db 10,13,"Enter your command:",10,13,"Command: ","$",10,13
string db ?

CODESEG                                    
proc OpenFile
;Open file
    mov ah,3Dh
    xor al,al
    lea dx,[filenameStr+2]
    int 21h
    jc openerror
    mov [filehandle],ax
    ret
openerror:  
    mov dx,offset ErrorOpenMsg
    mov ah,9h
    int 21h
    ret
endp OpenFile   

proc ReadFile
    mov ah,3fh
    mov bx,[filehandle]
    mov cx,255
    lea dx,[fileString]
    int 21h
    ret
endp ReadFile   

proc DeleteFile
    mov ah,41h
    lea dx,[filenameStr+2]
    int 21h
endp DeleteFile

proc DisplayFileString
    mov ah,09h
    lea dx,[fileString]
    int 21h 
endp DisplayFileString  

proc KeyStroke
    xor ax,ax
    int 16h
endp KeyStroke

proc WriteToFile
    mov ah,40h
    mov bx,[filehandle]
    mov cx,255
    lea dx,[fileString]
    int 21h
    ret
endp WriteToFile

proc CloseFile
    mov ah,3Eh
    mov bx,[filehandle]
    int 21h
    ret
endp CloseFile  

start:
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

    mov dx,offset szMsg1
    mov ah,9h
    int 21h
    jmp GetCommandLetter

_Error:

    mov dx,offset ErrorMsg
    mov ah,9h
    int 21h 

GetCommandLetter:
    mov dx,offset CommandMsg
    mov ah,9h
    int 21h

    mov ah, 1h
    int 21h
    mov bl,al   

    mov ah, 1h
    int 21h
    mov bh,al   
compare:    
    cmp bl,'/'
    jne _Error
    cmp bh,'e'
    je _exit

    cmp bl,'/'
    jne _Error
    cmp bh,'E'
    je exit

    cmp bl,'/'
    jne _Error
    cmp bh,'h'
    je _help

    cmp bl,'/'
    jne _Error
    cmp bh,'H'
    je _help

    cmp bl,'/'
    jne _Error
    cmp  bh,'1'
    je PrintLine

    mov dx,offset space
    mov ah,9h
    int 21h
    mov dx,offset FileNameLength
    mov ah,9h
    int 21h

    cmp bl,'/'
    jne _Error
    cmp  bh,'r'
    je GetFileName

    cmp bl,'/'
    jne _Error
    cmp  bh,'R'
    je GetFileName

    jmp _Error
_exit:
    jmp exit    

GetFileName:
    mov dx,offset space 
    mov ah,9h 
    int 21h
    mov dx,offset filenameStr
    mov bx,dx
    mov [byte ptr bx],13    ;8+1+3+1
    mov ah,0Ah
    int 21h
    mov dx,offset filenameStr + 2
    mov ah,9h
    int 21h


    mov byte ptr [filenameStr+2+8],0


    call OpenFile 
    call ReadFile
    call CloseFile 
    jmp GetCommandLetter



_help:  
    mov dx,offset help
    mov ah,9h
    int 21h
    jmp GetCommandLetter

PrintLine:
    mov dx, offset szHelloWorld
    mov ah, 9h
    int 21h
    jmp GetCommandLetter

exit:
    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h
END start
```

Comment: Before you open a file, you have to get its name from somewhere. Where and how are you filling the `filename` variable? Did you check in the debugger what does contain? It's not in the code...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can i get file name from user input in dos asm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36816865/how-can-i-get-file-name-from-user-input-in-dos-asm)

Comment: @Seva Alekseyev i've added the whole code

Comment: @RossRidge Unfortunately, that possible duplicate does not exist anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> filenameStr db 15 dup(?),0
> filename db ?,0
> ```

You have these two defines that deal with your problem. The second (*filename*) is too small to be of any use, and that's why your *deleteFile* procedure will fail! The first (*filenameStr*) is meant to be the input structure for the DOS input function. This is large enough but you need to initialize its first byte to something smaller than 15, I suggest 13 because that will allow for 8 characters + 1 dot + 3 characters + carriage return.

```
mov dx,offset filenameStr
mov bx,dx
mov byte ptr [bx],13    ;8+1+3+1
mov ah,0Ah
int 21h
```

When you want to display this text you need to terminate it with a **$** dollar sign, and be aware that the actual text starts at offset 2 within this structure. I solved it this way:

```
filenameStr db 13,0,13 dup("$")


mov dx,offset filenameStr + 2
mov ah,9h
int 21h
```

To open the file succesfully you need to first replace the carriage return by a zero, and again be aware that the text starts at offset 2.

Comment: i've changed the code as you said,                                                                     GetFileName:
 mov dx,offset space
 mov ah,9h
 int 21h

 mov dx,offset filenameStr
 mov bx,dx
 mov [byte ptr bx],15
 mov ah,0Ah
 int 21h
 mov dx,offset filenameStr
 mov ah,9h
 int 21h
 call OpenFile
 call ReadFile
 call CloseFile
 jmp GetCommandLetter      i'm not sure though,is it where i was supposed to change it? and am i supposed to change the code of the variable filenameStr to filenameStr db 13,0,13 dup("$")? since when i've launched the program,it said Error when i wanted to read a file

Comment: The code that you wrote in this comment, is the code that needs to be changed. And yes, also the define high up in the listing. If you still get an error on reading, it's probably because you didn't correct the *OpenFile* procedure like I indicated in my last paragraph.

Comment: i've changed the code, and i've uploaded the new full code in the question, did i change it right?

Comment: You forgot  to change `lea dx,[filenameStr]` into  `lea dx,[filenameStr+2] in OpenFile and in DeleteFile. Also, DX must point to a **buffer** for ReadFile, not to the filenameStr!!!

Comment: For the other changes, you erroneously made these in the part **below** *END start*. This is **not** part of your program!!!

Comment: how do i set the buffer variable? what am i writing there,since i dont have one,i'm not sure how to set up one

Comment: *WriteToFile* does is OK. Use the same `lea dx,[fileString]`

Comment: lea dx,[fileString] is instead of the buffer?

Comment: That's correct. You defined *fileString* as a buffer of 255 bytes.

Comment: it seams to not work yet, when i write the command /r it passes me to the /r/ line,and there i can write bova.txt since that's the name of the file,than,it writes Errortxta.txt and than passes me to a new line,when i press Enter,it starts spamming  "Enter your command: "Command:  " "Illegal Command,Try again!" and i have to quit DosBox

Comment: Please make **all** the changes to your *NEW-full code*. Now there's no telling what is correct or wrong.

Comment: Do re-read the last paragraph of my answer. You still need to replace the carriage return that DOS appended to the input with a zero, to make it suitable to be used by the *OpenFile* procedure! Example: If you inputted "BOVA.TXT" (8 characters) then write `mov byte ptr [filenameStr+2+8],0` before `call OpenFile`.

Comment: i didnt understand that part,how do you mean replacing the carriege return? can you show me that in the code?

Comment: thanks man,sorry for asking you so many questions,it's now displaying the message,hopefuly i wont have more problems!

Comment: i wanted to ask you another thing, how can i clear the msgString after reading the file,so i could read another file and the data wont be stepped and replaced in the string? i've described it better in the question i posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36829600/how-can-i-clear-string-dos-asm?noredirect=1#comment61230969_36829600